# Do Asian groceries carry vital wheat gluten?

Tags: flour, shopping, vital-wheat-gluten

I want to buy vital wheat gluten for bread baking but I've only had luck finding it at health food stores where it's quite expensive. I know seitan is made from vital wheat gluten so I was wondering if the powder is something that is commonly found at Asian groceries? If so, what would be the name for it?

Comment: Can you order from Amazon?

Comment: I'm in Australia, so it wouldn't be worth it because of shipping. The gluten isn't really that expensive. It was $7.50AUD for 500 grams, I believe, but I'm guessing it would last a long time. In any case, I'm sure Asian places would stock it cheaper if they did stock such a product.

Comment: "I know seitan is made from vital wheat gluten" ... that is the modern approach. The old-school approach is  to start with a high-gluten flour, kneading it to form the gluten, and iteratively washing out the (highly water soluble) starch from the (effectively insoluble) gluten fibre. More work, and harder to incorporate seasonings and texture altering ingredients. BTW, maybe someone chinese could comment on how commonly/uncommonly either of these methods are employed in households?

Answer (score 4):

Some Asian stores do carry it as it is used to make seitan. However, there isn't a blanket yes or no answer as it is up to the individual stores. The only thing you can do is to check the stores you can get to.

It may also be called gluten flour but, if you see this, be sure to read the label to ensure that it has 75% or more protein.